# Dynamics 365 Business Central: Show Notes globally

Tags: dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central, notesview

we use Dynamics 365 in our company.
Some of our customers have notes, such as travel expenses. However, these notes only appear in the customer page. These notes are also interesting, for example when creating an invoice.

In "creating invoce" there is also a note field. The information from the debtor does not appear there. The note field only refers to the page currently being viewed.

Is there a way to always display notes from a customer as soon as they are part of the process. So, for example, when creating an invoice or an order?

Thanks in advance.

We checked if there are more fields to display, but there is none which refers to debtor notes.

Comment: If possible, the notes should not be shown as pop-up.
Preferred, they would show on the right panel, where the field notes already exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out-of-the-box.

It will require custom development.

One solution could be to create a FactBox that retrieves the Notes related to the Customer.
The FactBox would then have to be added to the relevant pages.